# How to fix conflicting import?

Tags: android, okhttp

I am building an application for android and i have too conflicting imports.

```
    import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback;
    import okhttp3.Callback;

  mLoginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            }


        });
```

I am trying to initalize twitter login but i am also using okhttp3 for reading Json data. i am advice by the system to  Change signature of 'Callback' to match ''. But i would not be able to use okhttp if i do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use like this in your code

```
import okhttp3.Callback;

mLoginButton.setCallback(new com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

        }
    });
```

Comment: whenever conflicts occurs force ide to import in one line :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `okhttp3.Callback callback;` to force the usage of the okhttp3 callback once you have imported the twitter Callback.